# Extract recommendations for user from pivot table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I have a following pivot table with user/items number of purchases that looks like this:

```
originalName  Red t-shirt      Black t-shirt  ...     Orange sweater     Pink sweater
customer                                ...                                       
165                NaN             NaN  ...                  NaN               NaN
265                NaN             1.0  ...                  NaN               NaN
288                NaN             NaN  ...                  NaN               NaN
368                1.0             NaN  ...                  NaN               2.0
396                NaN             NaN  ...                  3.0               NaN
```

I wrote the method to get related items if I input one item, by using Pearson's correlation

```
def get_related_items(name, M, num):
    number_of_orders = []
    for title in M.columns:
        if title == name:
            continue
        cor = pearson(M[name], M[title])
        if np.isnan(cor):
            continue
        else:
            number_of_orders.append((title, cor))

    number_of_orders.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
    return number_of_orders[:num]
```

I am not sure what should be the logic to get the list of recommended items for a specific customer.

And how can I evaluate that?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to get? best item for specific customer?

Comment: @sygneto yes, that is what I am trying to get

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'customer':[165,265,288,268,296],
                'R_shirt':[np.nan,1.0,np.nan,1.0,np.nan],
                'B_shirt':[np.nan,np.nan,2.0,np.nan,np.nan],
                'X_shirt':[5.0,np.nan,2.0,np.nan,np.nan],
                'Y_shirt':[3.0,np.nan,2.0,3.0,np.nan]
                 })
print(df)
   customer  R_shirt  B_shirt  X_shirt  Y_shirt
0       165      NaN      NaN      5.0      3.0
1       265      1.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
2       288      NaN      2.0      2.0      2.0
3       268      1.0      NaN      NaN      3.0
4       296      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
df['customer']=df['customer'].astype(str)
df=df.pivot_table(columns='customer')
customer = '165'
print(df)
customer  165  265  268  288
B_shirt   NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0
R_shirt   NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
X_shirt   5.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
Y_shirt   3.0  NaN  3.0  2.0
best_for_customer=df[customer][df[customer]!=np.nan].to_frame().sort_values(by=customer,ascending=False).dropna()
print(best_for_customer)
         165
X_shirt  5.0
Y_shirt  3.0
```

variable `customer` is a name of customer that you want to check

Comment: This looks like it is just fetching all items that customer bought already? My goal is to output items that customer would be interested in, based on the similarity with other customers

Answer (score 0):

The expected rating for a user for a given item will be the weighted average of the ratings given to the item by other users, where the weights will be the Pearson coefficients you calculated. Then you can pick the item with the highest expected rating and recommend it.

Comment: Can you explain this more with some code example? I have figured out that I can rearrange this pivot, so I am using `M1 = df.pivot_table(index=['originalName'], columns=['customer'], values='number_of_orders')` for it.

Comment: Have a look at the memory-based methods at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering